# How to create a number as a decimal in excel

Tags: excel

I have two numbers for example

```
24,000 and 46,123
```

What I want is to create the number  24,000.46123  from this.

How can this be done in Excel?  I wont know how long the second number is so I can't just divide by 100000 for example

```
24,000 + (46123/100000)
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this with a formula in the cell? Or via VBA?

Comment: with a formula, but i will also need to in vba when i automate it, however i think in vba i know how to do it by creating a string and then converting it to a number, probably not a great solution tho!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With values in **A1** and **B1** in **C1** enter:

```
=A1+B1/(10^LEN(B1))
```

and set the format:

[image]

Comment: Was about to post `=A1+(B1/(10^LEN(B1)))` but yours is nicer and uses BEDMAS

Comment: nice, both answers are right I will choose yours as its purely maths based!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the cells of your spreadsheet:

Set cell A1 to 24000, set cell B1 to 46123, finally in cell c1 set `=value(concatenate(a1,".",b1)`